# 16.04 image tearing and lagging

Tags: drivers, 16.04, xorg, firefox, vlc

On ubuntu 16.04 when I watch movies in Kodi if I press the volume up/down hotkey I see little stutter in movie (cca les than a sec). And also if vlc is open and ff in background with YT I see image tearing and some sort of lagging. Why does this happen?

For Image tearing I already enabled the TearFree option but why does it happen with vlc when ff is in the bacgrund.

The TearFree option I enabled with:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

My pc is a laptop Lenovo z51-70 with i3 5005U and a hybrid intel/amd m360 card.

I know that most people wouldn't care if you see a stutter in kodi when you press the volume hotkey or if ff is in the background with YT and there is tearing in Vlc.